# Confusing situation LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am in a very confusion situation

I have a controller logic like this

```
public function book(Request $request)
{
  //setting API class
  $business = new API();

  //getting name and number for sending verification code
  $name = $request->name;
  $number = $request->number;

  //sending verification code to number 
  $business->sendVerificationCode($number);

 //sending user back to show a form to enter verification code
 return back()->with('modalForEnteringConfirmation', ' ');

}
```

I am sending the verification code to the requested number. 
I am returning back with a modal which has a form to enter the verification code.

My problem is to get that verificationCode value so that I can proceed further in my `book` controller

```
//receiving confirmation code
$code = $request->confirmation;

//booking if confirmation code matches
$book = $business->bookingNumber($name, $code);
```

Now, I cannot send variables in `back()` function, how am I supposed to get the confirmation code? I just cannot seem to get it.

Comment: Actually you can send variables in `back()` you're already doing it when using `with()`. Laravel flashes these in the session and then shares them with the views on the next request.

Comment: An easy way for this is to install the laracast flash  message package from github : https://github.com/laracasts/flash . super easy to use and you will be free from handling sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a flashed data to a *next request* by using the `with` on that `back` function. So that in your view you'll have to check that data either using `request()->session()->get()` or `session()` helper method:

Let's say you send the verification code through the controller like this:

```
...
return back()->with('verification_code', $verification_code);
```

Then in your view you'll include in the modal already the `verification_code`

```
<-- Say this is your modal content section -->
@if (request()->session()->has('verification_code'))
      {{ request()->session()->get('verification_code') }}
    // you should have the code here
@endif
```

Of course I don't know how you built your modal form, but when writing the html code, if you include that data as described above within the form then you should have it available anytime it finds it.

Comment: I actually cannot send data with `back()` function, it says `$verification_code` not found in my modal view

Comment: You won't have `$verification_code` in your view, you'll have `request()->session()->get('verification_code')` instead.

Comment: is this `verification_code` the variable `$verification_code`?

Comment: Also, from this view, how can I pass the `$verification_code` to the controller? is is possible to do that?

Comment: @Cowgirl you won't have it as a variable, the data you passed by using `back()` will be sent as a _session_ data so you can access it as I described. I believe what is unclear to you is that when you do such a thing with `view()` function its passed as variable, but for `\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` instance, its keeps in session.

Comment: @Cowgirl One way to have it in your view is to explicitly pass it when you are returning view instance from your controller i.e for example, `view('myview')->with('verification_code', $verification_code)` but for your case, I think the close to the best option is to use the flashed data or else you have to setup your project to switch between views rather than use previous page.